# list of figures doesn't appear

Tags: lists

I am using WinEdt7 and writing my thesis as a report class. I need to add `\listoffigures`, but whenever I write `\listoffigures` in my `.tex`, the program gives me an error which says

> "..missing }"

in one of my figure codes. But when I delete `\listoffigures`, it works well. Of course there is no "list of figures" page.

Here my main code showing how I write my figure codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, includefoot, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
\doublespacing
\titlepage{\textbf{\centerline {THE "... MODES"}
\centerline {OF A THREE .. LATTICE}}}

\noindent\rule{15cm}{0.4pt}\\

\centerline {A Dissertation}
\centerline {Submitted to}
\centerline {the AAAA University Graduate Board}


\noindent\rule{15cm}{0.4pt}\\

\centerline {In Partial Fulfillment}
\centerline {of the Requirements for the Degree of}
\centerline {Doctor of Philosophy}

\noindent\rule{15cm}{0.4pt}\\

\centerline {by}
\centerline {AAAA}
\centerline {August 2014}

someone,department

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\doublespacing
\chapter*{\center  ABSTRACT}
In this thesis...

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
\chapter*{\center ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
.....

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DEDICATION}
\chapter*{\large To my family}


\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand\contentsname{\centerline {TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table     }
\listoftables

 %
    \begin{figure}[!h]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{NeutronAAA}
      \caption{(Color on line) Summary of lattice dynamics measured in NaI along the [111] direction, showing the phonon dispersion curves measured at 90 K (dashed lines) and 555 K (red lines), including a dispersionless local mode (ILM) that appears in the gap between the branches of acoustic and optic phonons. [From AAA {\it et al.} (2013).]\label{BBBB}}
    \end{figure}
    %
\end{document}
```

I am writing my whole thesis chapters in one `.tex` file (I know it is shameful), so I tried to copy first main lines.

The error message is:

> "[3] [4] [5] [6] (C:Users\pc-f\Desktop\Thesis\AAThesis.toc)
>
> (C:Users\pc-f\Desktop\Thesis\AAThesis.lof)
>
> ! Missing } inserted.
>
> 1.4 ... hes the corner of the Brillouin zone.}}{20}
>
> ?"

This is my suspect figure code;

```
%
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{DOSQ}
  \doublespacing
  \caption{The frequency dependence of the two-phonon creation density of states $\rho^{(+,+)}_{\underline{Q}}(\omega)$ (in units of $\omega_0^{-1}$), for various values of the center of mass momentum $\underline{Q}$, (in units of $\pi/a$). (Top Left Panel) For momentum $\underline{Q}$ along the x-axis. (Top Right Panel) For momentum transfers $\underline{Q}$ along the (1,1,0) axis. (Bottom Panel) For $\underline{Q}$ along the diagonal of the Brillouin zone. It is seen that the density of states peaks up at the upper edge of the two-phonon creation continuum as the center of mass momentum $\underline{Q}$ approaches the corner of the Brillouin zone.}\label{DOSQ}
\end{figure}
%
```

Do you think something wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @faith: Your code is incomplete

Comment: @faith I think that the document you pasted (twice) is not relevant to the problem. Probably the error is in the caption of one of your figures (not neccesarily the one you pasted). Please, paste instead the exact error TeX is printing (with some of the previous lines in the log, as context)

Comment: @faith -- the problem is likely on line 4 of the `.lot` file.  take a look at that; if the text there matches what you've shown, "`1.4 ... hes the corner of the Brillouin zone.}}{20}`", you've got the right line.  then, if you can't figure out what is wrong, copy it into your question along with the error message and the line(s) from your main file that resulted in the `.lot` file entry (probably the table caption).

Comment: @barbarabeeton You mean the `.lof` file (and "figure caption") don't you?

Comment: @JLDiaz -- yes.  (i've got an appointment with my eye doctor next week.  sigh.)

Comment: I can confirm the pasted text has no problem compiling — though it should be amended.

Comment: I have only one figure which ends with "..the corner of the Brillouin zone." Even if I delete this figure, still having the same error message.

Comment: I mean I have many figures, but only one of them ends with "..the corner of the Brillouin zone."

Comment: @faith -- please rename the `.lof` file, to something like `xxx.lof-hold`, then, with the suspect figure absent (commented out is best, so you can recover it later), try rerunning.  as long as a faulty `.lof` file is present and being read in, you will continue to get the error.  if a rerun without that figure works (run it twice!), you know that's the problem figure/caption, and can concentrate your efforts on that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton--I renamed it, but not worked. I will make a new tex file then add the figures one by one. hopefully works. thanks again your time.

Comment: @faith Your caption is too long for a "list of figures" index (even if this is unrelated to your problem). Try writing a shorter version for the list of figures, like this: `\caption[Short description for the lof]{Your long description to appear under the figure}`

Comment: @JLDiaz-Thank you for your comment, I will make it short.